# Where to watch the original run of Chibi Maruko-chan (1990-1992)?

Tags: streaming-sites, chibi-maruko-chan

I cannot find a proper site to find all episodes of *Chibi Maruko-chan* anywhere. In some sites, I find only episode 80, but, according to the wiki, there are definitely more.

The original run was stated from 1990-1992, and about 142 episodes are said to be there. However, I haven't been able to find a place I could buy/stream the show anywhere. There seem to be new modifications to it, but, I'd like to watch the original one, the series from [1990-1992](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chibi_Maruko-chan_episodes).

Anywhere or any way I can get it, stream it, or purchase it?

Comment: Hi, take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Comment: I did write buy/stream, so yeah, I meant legal

Comment: I couldn't find that in popular streaming sites as well.

Comment: All though I am not sure if it contains the 1990 episodes, they do have an [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWHgQAAsB6LyYQhIm-IeJ5w) which is run by Nippon Animations.

Comment: @Dimitrimx , yeah, they have this new version which is dubbed, and a perfectly viewable show seems like a kid's show. The 1990's one was much better.